# Specific open covering in affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

Theorem 3.42 (Wedhorn and Görtz "Algebraic Geometry") states that, for $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$, there is a bijection between ideals of $A$ and closed subsechemes of $A$ given by $\mathfrak{a} \mapsto V(\mathfrak{a})$ (where the structural sheaf in $V(\mathfrak{a})$ is given by the pushforward of the structural sheaf of $\operatorname{Spec}(A/\mathfrak{a})$ via the canonical homeomorphism $\operatorname{Spec} A/\mathfrak{a} \to V(\mathfrak{a})$).

In order to prove this, he argues that it is enough that prove that if $i: Z \to X$ is the inclusion morphism and the associated map $\varphi: A \to \Gamma(Z, \mathscr{O}_Z)$ is injective, then $i$ is an isomorphism.

First, he shows that from the previous hypothesis, it follows that $i$ is a homeomorphism. So now we assume that $Z$ and $X$ have the same underlying topological space. In order to show that $\mathscr{O}_X \to \mathscr{O}_Z$ is an isomorphism, we have only to show that it is injective (because $i$ is a closed immersion). Then they set of to prove injectivity in the stalks. Let $x \in Z$, with $\mathfrak{p}_x$ the associated prime ideal in $A$, and consider the morphism $\mathscr{O}_{X, x} = A_{\mathfrak{p}_x} \to \mathscr{O}_{Z, x}$. It is enough to show that for each $g \in A$ such that $\frac{g}{1} \in \operatorname{ker}(\mathscr{O}_{X, x} \to \mathscr{O}_{Z, x})$, $g = 0$. To prove this, the book says we whould consider a finite open covering $Z = U \cup \bigcup_i U_i$ satisfying:

1. $(U, \mathscr{O}_Z|_U)$, $(U_i, \mathscr{O}_Z|_{U_i})$ are affine schemes.
2. $\varphi(g)|_U = 0, x \in U$ and $x \notin U_i$ for each $i$.

The first time I wrote the question I assumed that $U$ was fixed because we get it by choosing an affine neighborhood of $x$ such that $\varphi(g)|_U = 0$. But I guess it must be defined at the same time as the other $U_i$. I don't know why this open cover exists.

Comment: What have you tried/where are you stuck? Can you find an open subscheme of $X$ not containing $x$, for instance?

Comment: yes, $X \setminus \overline{\{x\}}$. Is it necessarily true that $\overline{\{x\}} \subseteq U$? If it is, that is the answer.

Comment: @user480840 surely not. I am suspicious of this claim, as you have presented it, though I could be mistaken. What if $X$ is irreducible, and $x$ is the generic point? Then every open set contains $x$, so if you are not given $U = X$ a priori, then constructing such a cover will not be possible. I will take a look at G&W...

Comment: @user480840 my point is that your post reads as if you are given the pair $(U, x)$, not just $x$, so your claim won't be true for an arbitrary open subset $U$ containing $x$. If you can choose $U$, then there is nothing to prove - you could just always take $U = X$, right?

Comment: Ok, I have stated it in a slightly different way. I try to write in a way that it seems more like the context (although without the full context).

Comment: I think you ought to present the full context - the claim is still not quite correct (take $X=\Bbb A^1$, $x=\eta$, $U=\Bbb A^1\setminus \{0\}$) and I think your interpretation is causing issues here. (H/t to Alex Wertheim for the counterexample which also shows that my previous comment was not really the right thing to say.)

Comment: I tried to provided the full context, maybe it makes more sense now.

Comment: Can you just post the exact text from the book that you're having trouble with (along with your interpretation, if you wish)? Part of the trouble here is that we're hearing the text second-hand through you, and if you've ever played telephone, you know how that can go.

Comment: The text is rather lengthy, but I highlighted the most important parts practically verbatim. If it stills seem fishy, I will post the full proof later (how can I do it without having to copy the entire proof in LaTex here?)

Comment: You could at least give the reference (title, author, edition). It's better if you can quote the text, but at least people who have access to the book, can check.

Comment: Sorry, the name of the book was written in an previous edit, I erased it and the beginning of the post thus seemed nonsensical. Its "Algebraic Geometry: Part 1: Schemes. With Examples and Exercises" by Wedhorn and Görtz. I believe I have posted the relevant part of the question, though. If it is unclear, I will write the full proof, highlighting what I don't understand. Thank you so much for your time and help.

Comment: This is a typo and the condition $x \notin U_i$ for all $i$ is not needed. Please see https://www.algebraic-geometry.de/errata/1/